# How do I alter the weights in this simple neural network?

Tags: math, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to learn about neural networks, but the material available online is pretty dense, and I just want to understand what happens in this particular, simple case.  That will help me move onto something more complex with hidden layers.

Let's say I have 2 inputs, 1 output, no hidden later.  Input and output are both real-valued.  I use the sigmoid function $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.

Say I get an output of A for some given weights W1 and W2, but I want an output of B.  I need to change the weights based on the error.

What explicitly do each of the weights change to when updated?

I've seen explanations online using the derivative of the sigmoid function, but I don't know where this comes from.  I've seen errors calculated as $\frac{1}{2}(A-B)^2$, and sometimes just as $A-B$.  It's confusing.

(Just realised there's no MathJax on stackoverflow.  Hopefully you can still read it.)

**UPDATE:** I might have figured it out, so if someone can confirm this, that would be great.

The new W1 = W1 + n * (X1) * (W1) * d * (e^x) / (e^x+1)^2
where n is learning rate, X1 is first input, X2 is second input, d is the error, or B-A. x=W1X1 + W2X2, and the function at the end is the derivative of the sigmoid function.  The other weight is similar:
new W2 = W2 + n * (X2) * (W2) * d * (e^x) / (e^x + 1)^2

(Typing this notation is horrible.)

Is this all correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The full derivation for this case is given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Derivation

Your formula corresponds to the first case "if j is an output neuron"; you simplified phi(x) (1-phi(x)) = (e^x) / (e^x+1)^2 with phi(x) = 1/(1+e^-x).